Reputation manipulation, take two.
There have been some odd upswings in the rep scores lately. I now know who's been doing this. I took two screen shots at different times yesterday, so it's obvious which user is "vote stuffing".
I'm not going to publicly call anyone out, but I sure hope this user refrains from further indiscriminate voting.

Just make sure when you vote, you vote for lots of great content -- not the same user over and over.

Well, it isn't me (optionally: this time). I've given up trying to get the Electorate badge. 

I don't think we should have a problem with bulk upvoting valuable content. In fact we need much more votes to establish a self-moderating community (no chance to go out of beta in the current state - ATM only @Shane + mods would have edit privileges). What we don't want is reciprocal voting (you upvote me, I upvote you), revenge downvotes and fake accounts. But I doubt this is what happens here. @Tangurena, you will have to wait a bit for the Electorate. ;-) At current pace we would need at least a couple of months to even get enough questions in total to make it attainable.
